# How to make a picture that would be updated every 30 seconds?

Tags: android

How to make a picture that would be updated every 30 seconds ?

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Try to use TimerTask https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use something like a thread to do this.

For example, below your image view:

```
Runnable imageUpdater = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
             try {
                 sleep(30000); // 30 seconds in milliseconds
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                 // Someone called thread.interrupt() and tried
                 // to stop the thread executing
                 return;
            }

            // Here load the image in the same way as above:
            // But you will need to go onto the UI thread first.
            image.post(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     Picasso.with(YourActivity.this).load( "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
                 }
            });
         }
    }
};
```

Then you just start the runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(imageUpdater);
```

Comment: Threads are not recommended in android, better to use handler or TimerTask.

Comment: @Neo, updated to use a handler instead. What does Android do that makes threads unfavourable?

Comment: Better to use TimerTask or call hanlder, as per their recommendation. Because Threads are nowhere connected to Activity lifecycle and hard to manage, like you can't stop them directly. Instead if you are using timer task you can stop it easily. And the best thing with handler, is that no need to think about their lifecycle, once activity will finish they will be stopped itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] imageLink = {http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png, 
                              http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png, http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png};

    int position = 0;

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(runnable);    
            }
        }, 30 * 1000, 30*1000);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Picasso.with(this).load(imageLink[position%imageLink.length]).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
           position++;
         }
    };
```

Hope the above code will help you :)